# Why aren't images showing up in Playground using markdown?

Tags: swift2, documentation, xcode7, markdown, swift-playground

The problem is that Im trying to learn the new documentation for swift using markdown but when I try to bring in an image from a URL in playgrounds it just shows the text, while working on a non-playground project it works but how do I make it work in playground?


This is what it looks like:

`//:  ![Playground icon](https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/swift/images/playgrounds.png "hover text")`

It just returns the words *Playground icon*

Comment: But the Apple Documentation saids it is possible to call URLs since I copied that above from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH17-SW1)

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit too quick there. I can reproduce the above problem myself, for some other url images as well local images. The sandboxing shouldn't affect markup...

Comment: I was able to use local images if they were under the resource folder in the playground but not from URL

Comment: As images in resource folder are available within sandbox restraints (for use "in code"), this possibly implies that the sandboxing somehow restricts also markup (which, afaik, it shouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the "**Render Documentation**"checkbox is checked in XCode. If not, like int the following screenshot, no image will be showed.

[image]